# Change options for a field in crud or sqlform on basis of another

Tags: javascript, jquery, web2py

I am creating a contact details application. I want to provide users with a form with fields of city and state. I want city field to have drop down options(similar to what one gets in SQLFORM for fields with IS_IN_SET(...) validators). The state field gets populated on selection of a city if for that named city, only one state exists(without form submission). If more than two states have the same city, then a drop down list should appear. Is there any shortcut method available for that in web2py like ajax or jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These options should get you on the right track:

- [Lazy options widget](http://dev.s-cubism.com/plugin_lazy_options_widget)
- [Cascading Drop Down Lists](http://www.web2pyslices.com/slices/take_slice/85)
- [Cascading Select Based on Python Lists](http://www.web2pyslices.com/slices/take_slice/89)
- [Cascading Drop Down Lists with Ajax](http://www.web2pyslices.com/slices/take_slice/144)

Comment: Thanks Anthony! You're really a genius :-)